# Utilizar data sem criar loop na pagina

Tags: javascript, html

tenho uma pagina que faço consultas por datas, com a data selecionada a pagina me retorna o resultado, ate ai ok, mas ai o cliente solicitou que mantivesse a data como um histórico para que ele não precisasse todo momento escolher a mesma data.

O código que fiz foi esse:

```
$('#dataCons').on('blur', function() {
                var cod = $(this).val();
                window.location="admagendamento.php?dataEsc="+cod;
                sessionStorage.setItem("dataEsc", cod);                                      
            });
```

Esse é quando escolho a data no campo, alem da pesquisa ele ainda guarda a data no sessionStorage, mas num próximo carregamento da pagina quando verifico se já existe uma data dentro do sessionStorage, e se existe executo a pesquisa com essa data guardada a pagina entra em loop, veja o codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var dataEsc = sessionStorage.getItem("dataEsc");
            if (dataEsc){
                window.location="admagendamento.php?dataEsc="+dataEsc;    
            }
```

Como faço para a pagina não entrar em loop?

Comment: Acredito eu que se você salvar esses dados em um cookie seria muito mais legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código entra em loop porque vc está usando o `window.location` que, como o nome sugere, altera a "localização" da janela para um novo endereço.

Não acho que seja boa ideia usar esse método para esse tipo de operação. Seria mais interessante usar Ajax para preencher parte da página com a informação desejada, mas isso te obrigaria a mudar algumas coisas da sua página.

Para resolver este seu problema bastaria verificar se `dataEsc` existe na URL antes de verificar o `sessionStorage`. Ex:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    if(params.has("dataEsc") === false) {
        var dataEsc = sessionStorage.getItem("dataEsc");
        if (dataEsc){
            window.location="admagendamento.php?dataEsc="+dataEsc;    
        }
    }
(...)
```

ps: não testei o código acima, pois estou no celular.

Comment: Sim resolveu, não havia pensado nessa possibilidade, agradeço